# Angular add .js script to service

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make a service for connection to GameSparks like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

var gamesparks = new GameSparks();

var gsKey = "XXXXXXXXXX";
var gsSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var gsCredentials = "";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GamesparksService {

  isLive = false;

  init() {

    if (this.isLive) {
        gamesparks.initLive({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    } else {
        gamesparks.initPreview({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    }

  }

  //Callback function to hmac sha256 a nonce with the secret. It's assumed you will have your own method of securing the secret;
  onNonce(nonce) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(nonce, gsSecret));
  }

  //Callback to handle when the SDK is initialised and ready to go
  onInit() {
    console.log("Initialised");
  }

  //Callback to handle async messages from the gamesparks platform
  onMessage(message) {
    console.log("onMessage: " + JSON.stringify(message["scriptData"]));
  }

}
```

Now, the script does not know what GameSparks() and CryptoJS is and I guess it doesn't recognize the GameSparks SDK.

The SDK is placed in this folder:

```
./assets/gamesparks/gamesparks.js
./assets/gamesparks/gamesparks-functions.js
./assets/gamesparks/hmac-sha256.js
```

Now my service script above is placed here:

```
./app/services/gamesparks.service.ts
```

How do I implement the SDK into the service script?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install it with npm. So you would have to install the packages:

```
npm install crypto-js
```

Sadly there is no package for the gamesspark-sdk. There you would have to import it from your assets source. Add the following lines in your code:

```
import * as gamesparks from './assets/gamesparks/gamesparks.js';
import * as gsf from './assets/gamesparks/gamesparks-functions.js';
import * as cryptojs from 'crypto-js'; //When installed by npm
```

Then you can use the functions by:

```
library.functionName()
```

Comment: Oh yes... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

To use a JavaScript library in TypeScript you use the syntax

```
import * as yourName from 'pathToLibrary';
```

and then use it with

```
yourName.functionInLibrary();
```